# ModuleNotFoundError even if module (app name) is installed

Tags: django

I want to start a project but when trying to makemigrations, I got ModuleNotFoundError even if my apps is "installed" in settings

I have 2 apps: authentication and blog
In authentication, I have override User model with AbstractUser and that all

Python 3.8.3 / Django 3.2.3

I've try to re-install librairies in my virtual env but doesn't works
I have checked for typ errors but there are no errors

whats is wrong?

Comment: Can you add settings.py and project structure?

Comment: I found the error. When I create project, don't know it create project folder with settings.py (that ok) and another folder with the name of the project and a second settings.py file... and I update the wrong settings.py file...